# Visual Studio 2019 Ver 16.9.2 にアップデートしたら、Xamarin forms iOS のRelease Buildで、プロビジョニングファイルが見つかりませんエラーになってしまいました。

Tags: ios, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Visual Studio 2019 で、xamarin forms を利用し、iOSとAndroidのアプリを開発しております(Xamarin formsは初めて)。
リリース版も先日App Storeに登録できましたが、Visual Studioが新しくなっているとのことで、バージョンアップ(Ver 16.9.2)を行ったところ、iOS のRelease Build で以下のエラーが出てipaファイルが作成されなくなってしまいました。

```
The specified iOS provisioning profile 'xxx' could not be found. Please enable Automatic Provisioning from the iOS Bundle Signing page.
```

署名IDも有効で、プロビジョニングプロファイルも正しいものを選択しています。
どなた様か、回避方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

#### 試したこと

- プロビジョニングファイルを再度新規作成し、実施しても同様の結果です（コンボボックスに展開されて選択）。
- ツール-オプション-Xamarin-Apple Accountsから、詳細表示で証明書は有効と表示され、プロビジョニングプロファイルの有効期限も十分です。

---＜＜＜ 別の問題が発生：IPAファイルが作成されません ＞＞＞-----
●ご質問させていただいた内容（プロビジョニングプロファイルが見つかりません）は、以下を実施して解決しました。
Visual Studio 2019・ツール・オプション・Xamarin・Apple Accounts・詳細の表示から、「すべてのプロファイルをダウンロード」を実施することで解決しました（以前この動作をしたことは、ありません）。
が、IPAファイルが作成されず、exe ファイルが作成されます。iOS IPA オプションは「IPAをビルドする」になっております。
●又、ツール・iOS・ビルドサーバーにIPAファイルを表示 を実施すると、ペアリンクした Mac に最後にリリースした過去の日付で表示されますが、同時に exe も存在し、その日付も過去の同一のものでした（Windows側のbinは、ほぼ同一ファイルが格納されていますが、exeだけは現在の日時で表示されています）。
●このことから、以前(VSアップグレード前)は、Mac上で Build を行い IPA ファイルが作成され、現在は、Windowsで Build を行い IPA ファイルが作成されないという事なのでしょうか？
私の願いは IPA ファイルの作成です。どなた様か、ご存じの方がいらしたらご教示願えませんでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

Xcodeを最新版にアップデートしてはどうでしょうか。
質問者様のケースと同様ではないですが、
ビルドできていたものが、ビルド失敗するようになったことがあります。
私の場合は、結局、iOS最新化、Xcode最新化、VS2019 for Mac最新化（順序は失念）でビルドできるようになりました。
慎重に自己責任でご参考ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
自己解決しました。VSのUpdateにより、ターゲットが「ローカルデバイス」ではIPAが作成されなくなったようです。
「リモートデバイス」にしたところ、正しく作成されました。設定ミスのたぐいで申し訳ありませんでした。